# Overlay DIV and Links In and Outside of It

Tags: html, click

Is there a way for me to make links clickable both in an overlay DIV and on the surface behind the DIV?

I know about `POINTER-EVENTS: None;` but it is not a solution in this case because it only makes links clickable on the surface behind the overlay DIV making links in the DIV untouchable.

Sorry if this is a duplicate question.

Comment: Can you provide an example in a Codepen or JS Fiddle of what you're working with?

Comment: Basically, I have a fixed `HEADER`, in which is the overlay `DIV`. When I add `POINTER-EVENTS: None;` on `HEADER`, the `DIV` in the `HEADER` can be clicked through on the links behind the `HEADER`, but I can not make them be both clickable (links within the `DIV` on the `HEADER` and links on the page behind `HEADER`). The pen: [link]https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZdmrzM You can see, with the current settings, that you can not click through the semi-black `HEADER`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property you want here is `z-index`. Specifically, you want to make it higher on the anchor tags you want to click on than on the header.

First, you'll want to add a class to the anchor tags (let's call it `above-header`) for specificity, so that the links all look like this:

```html
<A href="https://www.google.com" class="above-header">Link</A>
```

Then you'll want to add the following CSS to apply the new positioning to the anchor tags:

```css
.above-header {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1001;
}
```

`position: relative` will make the `z-index` applicable to those anchor tags without moving them at all, while `z-indez` will raise them above the header (and make them clickable) as long as their `z-index` value is larger than that of the header (which is currently 1000).

I would also lower the `z-index` on `.header-area` to 1, and then make the `z-index` on the anchor tags 2, but that's mostly a matter of code style.

Comment: Where to add the `above-header` class, to the `DIV` on the `HEADER`?

Comment: The anchor tags AKA the links AKA `<a>` tags

Comment: I did add the class to `<A>`s but still no success. And I want links directly behind the `HEADER` to be clickable as well as the links in the `HEADER`. I saved the changes in the pen.

Comment: You also need to add the `above-header` class to all of the `<A>` elements in the HTML so that their opening tags read `<A href="https://www.google.com" class="above-header">`. I've updated my original answer to make that clearer. You'll also be able to remove the `!important` from the CSS

Comment: Yes, I did not understand you well initially. Now it works well. Thank you.